# Angularjs default value for a dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown that returns data which works fine. 
I need to have the first value to be "Select a number"
I have tried ng-init as suggested online by people but not working

How can I set a default value?

```
    <div class="selection">
        <label for="accountNumber" class="lbl">("Customer Number:")</label>
        <select id="accountNumber" ng-init="somethingHere = options[0]" class="sel" name="accountNumber" ng-model="vm.defaultAcctNumber" ng-options="item for item in vm.retrieveAliasName">                              
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Just add `<option value="">Select a number</option>` inside your select. And remove ng-init.

Comment: This works but it doesn't make it  the default when the page loads

Comment: Yes, it does: http://plnkr.co/edit/WF1eu8A9QAYTZD2RXux8?p=preview. If it doesn't in your code, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, as I just did.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud set the **`vm.defaultAcctNumber`** which is the **`ng-model`** , It should be,

```
 <div class="selection">
        <label for="accountNumber" class="lbl">("Customer Number:")</label>
        <select id="accountNumber" ng-init="vm.defaultAcctNumber = options[0]" class="sel" name="accountNumber" ng-model="vm.defaultAcctNumber" ng-options="item for item in vm.retrieveAliasName">                              
        </select>
 </div>
```